# Botocore Error with Heroku: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku, amazon-s3, botocore

I deployed my Python Flask web-app on Heroku and everything works fine except for when I try to upload files to Amazon S3 Bucket.

I've tried to manually set the S3 keys to the Config Vars on Heroku website and also in Terminal but to no avail.

```
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720789+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720791+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720793+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720795+00:00 app[web.1]: operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720797+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720799+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720801+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720803+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720805+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 132, in _send_request
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720807+00:00 app[web.1]: request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720809+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 116, in create_request
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720811+00:00 app[web.1]: operation_name=operation_model.name)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720813+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720815+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720817+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720819+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720823+00:00 app[web.1]: response = handler(**kwargs)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720825+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720827+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.sign(operation_name, request)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720829+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 157, in sign
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720832+00:00 app[web.1]: auth.add_auth(request)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720834+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 425, in add_auth
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720836+00:00 app[web.1]: super(S3SigV4Auth, self).add_auth(request)
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720838+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720840+00:00 app[web.1]: raise NoCredentialsError
2019-07-17T19:23:49.720847+00:00 app[web.1]: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

The error is "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials" even though I properly set the S3 keys in my Flask app (it works just fine on localhost).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who encounter the same issue, I figured it out. So I initially set my S3 bucket's credentials in both my code and `Settings` on Heroku with my own variable names instead of the seemingly standard names that are `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. It's a bit constrained but in order for the credentials to work correctly, you have to name them exactly `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

Comment: I followed your answer, but still get the same error. In my requirements.txt, I got boto, botocore and boto3 installed in my app. Still gives the No Credentials Error in the Heroku log.

Comment: Can you check again to see if all of the credentials (like the two mentioned above and `S3_BUCKET_NAME`) are set up properly on Heroku? If it works on localhost and not on Heroku, the only reason I can think of is that the credentials are not set up properly in `Settings` on Heroku. Also check out this site too if you haven't already https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually managed to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239813/credentials-cant-be-located-for-s3-flask-app-in-heroku/62239969#62239969

Comment: That's great. Glad you figured it out (: